# How to fix outliers in Ramachandran plot using Coot

Tags: structural-biology, pdb, coot

I have the following Ramachandran plot generated by **[Coot](https://www2.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/personal/pemsley/coot/)**:

[image]

Notice that it has high outliers content (red dots). I want to manually drag those
red dots into some part of the region. Eventually, I expect it to be reflected
in the coordinates so that I can save it as a new PDB file.

How can I achieve this?

G.V.

Comment: Surely the first place to ask would be the mailing list for this very specialized software. Have you done this?

Comment: https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/wa-jisc.exe?A2=ind2207&L=COOT&O=D&P=2725

Comment: This was asked also on [chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/166434/how-to-fix-outliers-in-ramachandran-plot-using-coot) and [mattermodelling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9390/how-to-fix-outliers-in-ramachandran-plot-using-coot)